# the size of distance between two pointers

Tags: c, pointers, printf, pointer-arithmetic

```
void main() {
    int a = 2;
    int *p = &a;
    int *q = p++;
    printf("%d %d\n", p, q);
    int b = p - q;
    printf("%d", b);
}
```

Why does it print `1`? I've tried with other pointers but didn't succeed. I thought it would print the size of `int` because the distance between them is `1 * sizeof(int)` but it prints `1`.

Comment: It's pointer arithmetic. It only gets converted to an `int` after the substraction.

Comment: The validity of your addressing in this code notwithstanding, pointer arithmetic is based on the *type* of the pointer. There is one `int` between `p` and `q` (remember? you advanced `p` by one with `p++`). Thus, `p-q` is one.

Comment: It works like array indexing. The second element of an `int` array is `array[1]` not `array[4]`. Note that with a pointer, `*(p+1)` is identical to `p[1]`.

Comment: Just as adding an integer to a pointer scales the integer by the element size, so does subtracting two pointers scale the difference by the reciprocal of the element size.  So `p1 + (p2 - p1)` is `p2`, as you'd expect (assuming `p1` and `p2` point to elements of the same array).

Answer (score 4):

> why it prints 1?

Because C specifies pointer subtraction as the **difference in the indexes** (subscript) of the array, not the **difference in address** values.

1 past the object is like the an array element after the `int a;`

> For the purposes of these operators, a pointer to an object that is not an element of an array behaves the same as a pointer to the first element of an array of length one with the type of the object as its element type. C17dr § 6.5.6 7

> When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object; the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two array elements. The size of the result is implementation-defined, and its type (a signed integer type) is `ptrdiff_t` defined in the `<stddef.h>` header. § 6.5.6 8

Subscript 1 - subcript 0 --> 1.

The result is 1 even if `int a` was `char a` or `long double a`.

Answer (score 2):

For starters according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

To output pointers you have to write

```
printf("%p %p\n", ( void * )p, ( void * )q);
```

In the initializer of the pointer `q`

```
int* q = p++;
```

there is used an expression with the postfix increment operator. Its value is the value of the operand before incrementing.

So the pointer `q` is initialized by the address of the variable `a` and as a side effect the pointer `p` is incremented and points to the memory after the object `a`. That is between the addresses (in the extent of memory bounded by these addresses) stored in the pointers `p` and `q` there is stored only one object `a`. So according to the pointer arithmetic the result of the expression `p - q` is `1`.

On the other hand, the difference between the addresses stored in the pointers `p` and `q` is equal to the value of `sizeof( int )` that is to the value of `sizeof( a )`.

If you will write for example

```
int b = ( char * )p - ( char * )q;
```

then the value of `b` will be equal to `sizeof( a )` because in this case the memory occupied by the variable `a` is interpreted as a character array and `sizeof( char )` is always equal to `1`.

Comment: `void main()` is OK per C spec: "or in some other implementation-defined manner." C17dr § 5.1.2.2.1 2 and certainly not the key issue to the post.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I doubt that used by him compiler specifies such declaration of main.:)

Comment: If used by OP or not, C does allow other `main()` signatures and saying `main()` "**shall** be declared like" (IMO is incorrect) distracts from this otherwise good answer.

Comment: "the difference between the addresses stored in the pointers p and q is equal to the value of sizeof( int )" is technically amiss too.  Address converted to integers and then subtracted are not specified as such to be the size of an `int`- even if it overwhelming commonly seen.  Doing math on integers converted  from pointers makes some sense when a linear byte memory model is used, yet other memory models exist.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I can not agree. The difference between the pointers has the type ptrdiff_t and yields the size of element of an array of the type int. A single object in such a case is considered as an array with one element.

Comment: `p-q` is indeed 1 and type `ptrdiff_t`.  This answers "the difference between the addresses stored in the pointers p and q is equal to the value of sizeof( int ) that is to the value of sizeof( a )" sounds like you are referring to subtraction of of integers converted from pointers.  On re-reading, perhaps re-phrase to: "the difference between the addresses stored in the pointers p and q is equal to the value of sizeof( a ) _in units of_ sizeof( int)". Or the like.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica `int main()` (and `void main()`) is actually getting rejected by clang in strict C23 mode. (Although the C23 support is otherwise incomplete still, naturally) C does however otherwise allow implementation-defined forms, particularly for freestanding systems. The normative text about the form of main() that Vlad refers to here is from the hosted systems subchapter, so it isn't some universal truth.

Answer (score -2):

There are a few errors in this code:

1. The return type of main() should be int instead of void.
2. The printf() statement has two integer format specifiers, but the arguments passed are pointers, which are not guaranteed to have the same size as integers. Therefore, using the %d format specifier to print pointers is not correct. You can use the %p format specifier to print pointers.
3. The variables p and q are pointers to int, so the difference between them (i.e., p - q) should be divided by the size of int to get the number of elements between them.

Here is the corrected code:

#include <stdio.h>

```
int main() {
int a = 2;
int* p = &a;
int* q = p++;
printf("%p %p\n", p, q);
int b = (p - q) / sizeof(int);
printf("%d", b);
return 0;
```

}

This code will print the memory addresses of p and q, followed by the difference between them in terms of the number of int elements.

Comment: No: `(p - q)` is the the difference in `int` elements, and `(p - q) * sizeof(int);` is the difference in bytes.